# how to show textarea only based on selecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

now i'm creating comment reply task. but the problem when i click link reply, it show all textarea to every comment. How to show that textarea only based on selecting comment only?

```
tpl file

{if $entries.comment|default:''}
            {foreach from = $entries.comment name = data item = data key=k }


<a class="a_reply" href="reply_form"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt<strong>reply</strong></span></a>

 <div class="reply_form" id="formid()" style="display:none;">

        <form action="/commenter/web/index.php"  method="Post" >
        <input type = "hidden" name ="m" value = "{$m}" /> 
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="{$data.comment_id}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="{$data.user_id}"/>
        <input type = "hidden" name ="c" value = "do_add_comment_reply" /> 

        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Please leave a reply of the comment "></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="btn_reply"  name="btn_reply" class="btn btn-primary" value="Reply">

        </form>
        </div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
      $(".a_reply").click(function()
      {
        if($(".reply_form").is(":visible"))
        {
          $(".reply_form").hide();
        }
        else
        {
        $(".reply_form").show();
        }
    return false;

    });
    });
```

Comment: It's not Smarty related in fact. You need to set different ids for forms/buttons and use it when clicking on specific button

Comment: thank you marcin nabialek, can you elaborate with the code because i'm new programmer.

Comment: now i understand, solved already. thank you marcin nabialek